# Only display posts that are in multidimensional meta_value

Tags: wp-query

So i want to retrive a list with the posts that are in the meta_key "_blocks" and in that there is a multidimensional array with "areas" called left, right ,top etc. And within them there are assigned post_id:s. Like this:

```
Array
(
[left] => Array
(
[0] => 450
[1] => 452
[2] => 460
[3] => 451
[4] => 454
[5] => 449
[6] => 455
)

[right] => Array
(
[0] => 460
[1] => 455
[2] => 454
[3] => 453
)

)
```

The query look like this now.. Im a little confused right now how to archive this..

Before this im running a foreach as you can see on $areas as $area. And `$type_areas` holds etch post_type:s.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type_areas[$area['area']],
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_key' => '_blocks',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'left',
        'value' =>  '450', // just testing...
        'compare' => 'IN',
      )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

   $output .= '<li data-id="'. $query->post->ID .'" data-area="'. $area['area'] .'"><p>'. get_the_title() .'</p><span>'. $query->post->post_type .'</span></li>';

endwhile;
```

**UPDATE**

So i ended upp with a simple SQL-query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT post_id FROM kwido_postmeta WHERE meta_value REGEXP \'"'. $area['area'] .'";a:[[:digit:]]+:{[^}]*"'. $mainpost->ID .'"\'';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

That looks after the current post_id and area with a regex, then if found get the post_id..

```
$post_ids = array();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $post_ids[] = $result['post_id'];
}
```

With the post_id:s i make the query with `post__in` parameter which accept arrays.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type_areas[$area['area']],
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post__not_in'   => $post_ids
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

So i ended upp with a simple SQL-query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT post_id FROM kwido_postmeta WHERE meta_value REGEXP \'"'. $area['area'] .'";a:[[:digit:]]+:{[^}]*"'. $mainpost->ID .'"\'';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

That looks after the current post_id and area with a regex, then if found get the post_id..

```
$post_ids = array();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $post_ids[] = $result['post_id'];
}
```

With the post_id:s i make the query with `post__in` parameter which accept arrays.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type_areas[$area['area']],
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post__not_in'   => $post_ids
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```